# Java Inheritance Query

Tags: java, inheritance

Say I have two classes where SubClass inherits from (extends) SuperClass.

What is the difference between:

`SuperClass obj1 = new SubClass();`

and:

`SubClass obj2 = new SubClass();`

Both will look to the constructor of the Superclass and initialise it (the correct one, obviously). Both have access to the superclass implementations. But one is (as far as I am aware) a subclass wrapped in a superclass (the first example) and the other is a subclass object (the second example).

How will this effect the way code is run and interpreted?

What are the real world issues that a developer needs to be aware of regarding how these two objects differ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Google for "Polymorphism".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference with initializing it as a superclass is that if the subclass implementation has methods which the superclass does not, they will not be accessible via this object reference.

But "internally", this is *still* an instance of the subclass; so, if you call a method defined in the superclass but the subclass has overriden it, it is the subclass' method which is called: the JVM looks up methods from the more specific to the more general.

As a convoluted example, let us take `Object` and `String`:

```
final Object o = "Hello!"; // in fact this calls new String("Hello!")

o.toString(); // <-- uses String's .toString(), not Object's

// Can't do that: String defines .subString() but Object does not
o.subString(1);
```

Comment: A little googling on "virtual method call" or "virtual table" may help him understand things better

Comment: I liked this answer but if you don't mind my asking I am not 'initializing' it as a superclass, am I not more casting it? I certainly am not 'instantiating' it...?

Comment: See my edit. The JVM will initialize a `String`, but at your demand, you will access it as if it were a reference to one of its superclasses, here `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to think what the compiler knows about and what the runtime knows and a simple example:

```
public class Product {
    public double getPrice() {...}
}

public class Book extends Product() {
    public int getPageCount() {...}
}

and a simple program:
    Product p = new Product();
    p.getPrice(); // OK
    p.getPageCount(); // compiler error

    Book b = new Book();
    b.getPrice(); // OK
    b.getPageCount(); // OK

    Product pb = new Book();
    pb.getPrice(); // OK
    pb.getPageCount(); // compiler error

// but we can still use the getPageCount() of pb;
    ((Book)pb).getPageCount();   // compiles

// however if pb was not a Book then you would get a runtime error (ClassCastException)
```

You can test for the actual class by:

```
if (pb instanceof Book) {
    ((Book)pb).getPageCount();
}
```

This is often necessary when developing classes, but if your code has a lot of `instanceof` it probably needs rethinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
SuperClass obj1 = new SubClass();
```

What you're seeing here is a type of *substitutability*. What this means is, let's say you make another sub class of `SuperClass`, `SiblingClass`. Without using the superclass reference type, we would have to change more code, getters and setters, collections that might want to use it. By referencing them as the supertype, all you need to do is pass in the new `SiblingClass` object on construction.